# Responsive Layout with same growing gaps in each row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container with a random number of elements which should always **align on the left side**. The container width can increase or decrease.

If the container size is increasing then the first element from the row+1 should go one row back and should appear on the right side. But it should only go one row back if it can fit there with a padding on the left and right side.

While the element does not have space one row abouve, then the space between the elements should grow until the element from row+1 can fit in this row.

The same functionality should work also in the reverse way.

**Here is my code:**

```css
.container {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.container:after {
  display: block;
  content: " invisible node ";
  flex(999 999 auto);
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p6k537ep/

My Problem ist that in the second row the space between the elements is not the same as in the first row (It depends how many elements are there).

**Edit:**

But it is working that the elements from the second row can only move one row abouve if they have anough space. The Gap is growing in the correct way in the first row but not in the second one.

Comment: correct your after element like this `.container:after {
  display: block;
  content: " invisible node ";
  flex:999;
}` .. this syntax `flex(999 999 auto);` is invalid

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for your answer, I changed it and it works. But the second problem now is that the gap between the elements is not the same. Have you any solution for this?

Comment: you cannot make the same gap as you have different flex-grow ... so it will be a bit difficult in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `margin` property on the `:after` pseudoelement to keep the blocks together.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/b1mbg4aq/)

```css
.container {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.container:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-left: auto; /* added */
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: still the gap is not the same

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you only change space-arround to space-between it looks better on smaller container sizes. Then I will accept this answer!

Comment: @ValentinGavran I agree that `space-between`looks better, up to you do decide what you prefer. Can you use CSS `grid` instead of flex?

Comment: +1 for using Grid for the beautiful regular alignment (and simpler left-aligned layout or different alignment in the last row as a fallback)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is not solvable in Flexbox without adding invisible non-semantic helper elements to hold the horizontal rhythm of the last row (with the same width and horizontal margins as `.item`s, but zero height).

However, this is easily solvable in CSS Grid, which seems perfect for this:

```css
.container {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 60px);
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: start;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

and *kind of* solvable with inline-blocks, using the similar pseudo-element hack and some "magic" of the inline formatting:

```css
.container {
  min-height: 400px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 5px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container:after {
  display: inline; /* it's important, it should continue the same line! */
  /* each character below acts as an invisible placeholder for the item */
  /* with em dashes, they would be 1em (5px here) wide each */
  content: '— — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — ';
  letter-spacing: 55px; /* expand each placeholder to the item width */
  word-spacing: -56px; /* collapse the whitespaces */
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

But, honestly, I'd not recommend using the second option in production. Left-aligning the items instead would probably be a better fallback for browsers that don't support Grid.